# how to select some text in word and paste in to xml document using macro?

Tags: xml, vba, ms-word, macros

I am creating a xml from a word document using macro,
I want to paste copied text from word document to xml, I am using below code to select the text

```
Sub ShowSelection()
    Dim strText As String
    strText = Selection.Text
End Sub
```

How would I paste the selected text into an xml?

Comment: Are you trying to use the macro to tag the text in some way? Or are you just trying to speed up the copy/paste so that you don't have to move between documents? Can you create the XML in a separate Word document?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about Word macros but why don't you just read the word document as a string manually parse it as XML in your favorite language?

Comment: Hi,I want to create an xml using word document, the document will have "title","subject" & "description". i want to select 'title' from word document and paste it within a tag in an xml.            EX===  OUTPUT = OUTPUT + "<Title>" + "</Title>" & vbCrLf , I want title to be placed in title tag in an xml.

Comment: for me at least, this could be accomplished easiest in C# or VB.  if all the documents have the same layout as you said, using even XMLReader would be fairly straightforward...I'll take a look at some word macros later tonight but I could post a code example for you earlier if you'd like

Comment: Hi Mike, my priority is to create XML from word document, i used macro ,if it is easiest in C# or VB, please help me with code.

Comment: I'm not sure it's easier with VB.NET or C# but it's certainly more lightweight with VBA. I would probably code the XML export in VBA and use MSXML (6.0) to check the resulted output "well formness".